# how to stop Page refreshing ( Jumping) when The browser window is resized?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

when I click on the button, load the page, it loads fine. Once I resize the browser, this page keeps refreshing. I have copied a section of my layout page, that  handles the button. Can you please let me know if I am missing something ?

```
<div class="header-elements d-none">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
<a class="btn btn-link btn-float text-default" asp-area="" asp-controller="Device" asp-action="HeatMap" role="button"><i class="icon-bars-alt text-primary"></i><span>Statistics</span></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have any javascript code?

Comment: I do have in my layout page to render a nav bar. There are other links in the page. so page doesn't keep refreshing for other links and thought it might not be that JavaScript that could cause that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there are no listeners registered on the 'resize' event.
That way your page may become indifferent to screen sizes, i.e., unresponsive depending on how responsiveness was achieved.

[image]

It is possible to load the content for all screen sizes in which case there will be no need to make a trip to the server if window size changes.

Comment: Changing the bootstrap styling fixed the issues. Thank you for your suggestion. I wasn't running any listeners and I couldn't find them